# product re-design

Tags: usability, user-research, ux-field, methodology

Which methods aside from user testing are suitable when designing for product re-design? Participatory design is an option but wanted to explore some other methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the best and easy ways is to go through all the reviews of products in that category.

for ex. If I had to re-design a furniture website, I would go through google reviews of all furniture websites and stores, this gives a lot of genuine insights about a user and can help you come up with amazing insights, features and ideas for re-design

Answer (score 2):

To add to the above answers, It is good to do analysis on what are the pros and cons of an existing site, moreover, you can do [SWOT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SWOT_analysis)(Strengths and weaknesses, opportunities and threats) type of analysis.
Identifying your website's strengths and weaknesses will benefit on new designs.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by optimization?

I don't think participatory design is the right way to design for optimization . Participatory design is a way to get buy-in / permission to make design changes from other people within the company.

Optimization usually means you are trying to improve something when compared to different options, it's a quantitative method. It's usually done via A / B tests with few variables as possible. You do solution A x B, check that B is successful, then you do B x C check that B is successful, then you do B vs D and check that D is successful.

IF you want to improve a product in general for the user you could use a north star metric. Example, for something like Uber it could be completed rides per user. The product is usually "successful" when it becomes sticky (habit-forming).

Comment: thanks for the feedback; we are not trying to compare designs rather improve/re-design a feature.

Comment: Can you be more specific? What kind of feature in what kind of application?What is the goal of the feature? what is the user goal?